# Dropping duplicate rows based on column value by using the nearly equal criteria in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I've a pandas dataframe and it contains some duplicate rows so i want to remove them but with a condition:

```
        wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave        rv
0    4050.32    3  0.28269  0.07365  22.16080  4050.311360  0.639507
1    4208.98    5  0.48122  0.08765  44.90035  4208.972962  0.501295
2    4208.98    6  0.49994  0.08220  43.74591  4208.974061  0.423016
3    4512.99    2  0.19428  0.09145  18.91216  4512.981301  0.577864
4    4512.99    2  0.21029  0.08860  19.83386  4512.981389  0.572018
5    4520.22    7  0.65300  0.11791  81.95775  4520.214169  0.386727
6    4520.22    4  0.66772  0.11591  82.38548  4520.212833  0.475334
7    4523.08    6  0.13789  0.11303  16.59034  4523.060226  1.310633
8    4523.40    1  0.41672  0.09892  43.87775  4523.390305  0.642545
9    5797.87    3  0.27062  0.15473  44.57125  5797.850820  0.991747
10   5797.87    4  0.28240  0.14991  45.06534  5797.848945  1.088698

dir1 = os.listdir('/home/Desktop/computed_2d/')
for filename in dir1:
    if filename.endswith('.ares'):
       df1 = pd.read_table(path1+filename, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8,10),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave','rv'],delimiter=r'\s+')

       #dup_rows gives the duplicate rows on the basis of column 'wave'
       dup_rows = df1[df1.duplicated(['wave'], keep=False)]

       computed_rv = 0.50641
```

Now what i want to do is like, i want to drop the duplicate row whose value for `df1.rv` is nearly equal to the value of `computed_rv`.

For example: from the row 1 and 2, i want to keep row 1 because the value of `df1.rv` is nearly equal to `compted_rv`.

the values could be lower or higher than `computed_rv` like (0.34 and 0.30) or (0.99 and 1.8) then i want to keep the rows whose value for `df1.rv` is near to `'computed_rv'` , like here i would want to keep the ones with 0.34 and 0.99

How can i do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

#### `query`

```
computed_rv = 0.50641
tol = 0.01

df1.query('abs(rv - @computed_rv) < @tol')

      wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave        rv
1  4208.98    5  0.48122  0.08765  44.90035  4208.972962  0.501295
```

---

#### `is_close`

```
computed_rv = 0.50641
tol = 0.01

df1[np.isclose(df1.rv, computed_rv, atol=tol)]

      wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave        rv
1  4208.98    5  0.48122  0.08765  44.90035  4208.972962  0.501295
```

---

#### Pandas

```
computed_rv = 0.50641
tol = 0.01

df1[df1.rv.sub(computed_rv).abs().lt(tol)]

      wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave        rv
1  4208.98    5  0.48122  0.08765  44.90035  4208.972962  0.501295
```

Comment: i didn't understand the first step? Can you explain what's happening in each step??

Comment: It is three different approaches.  **Not** three steps.  You can choose any of them to accomplish the same task.

Comment: i used the pandas one, and it gave me an empty dataframe? What did i do wrong now?

Comment: You need to set your tolerance appropriately `tol`

Comment: Yeah it worked, thanks.! there are some rows like row 9,10 in question where the values of 'df1.rv' is a bit far from the 'computed_rv' so here it's dropping them. But i want keep the one  whose value is more or less equal to the 'computed_rv' , for example, here its row 9. How can i do that?

Comment: yeah, the values could be lower or higher than 'computed_rv' like (0.34 and 0.30) or (0.99 and 1.8) then i want to keep the ones whose values is near to 'computed_rv' , like here i would want to keep the ones with 0.34 and 0.99.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix a threshold of how much the rv should match and exclude rows which are not matching to specific condition, here i have used 10% increment and decrement to 'rv' column to computed rv

```
computed_rv = 0.50641
threshold =  0.1*computed_rv
df[(df.rv.ge(computed_rv-threshold) & df.rv.le(computed_rv+threshold))]
```

Out:

```
    wave    num stlines fwhm    EWs MeasredWave rv
1   4208.98 5   0.48122 0.08765 44.90035    4208.972962 0.501295
6   4520.22 4   0.66772 0.11591 82.38548    4520.212833 0.475334
```

Comment: I wanted to remove only 16 rows but it removed almost all the rows?? I want to remove the duplicates rows of column 'wave' by applying the nearly equal criteria on column 'rv'

Comment: haa, you can reduce teh threshold value, now i set to 0.1*computed_rv as 10 % , you can reduce the value to 0.03(3%) or any related for your convenience :-)